# css how to remove blank space at the bottom of prined pdf page

Tags: css

Need some help - no solutions onr stackoverflow not working for me :/

I'm trying to make simple "label" to print.

Have css
@media print page size set at 80mm 120mm portrait;

in HTML
main div with label content is set to 80x120mm
(no margins, body also no margins, no paddings).
Everything is almost ok but while printing to pdf it add white space (some kind of footer) on the bottom (about 4mm).
The pdf file have 80x120mm but my content is shorter.

I thought it can be overflow ?
If I add "overflow: hidden" to @media print @page
nothing happen
If i add "overflow: hidden to @media print html, body
content of the www is cut verticly in half(3/4) but on print pdf horizontaly it's ok, but it's move to another page verticly...

Part of CSS:

```
:root{
    --label-width: 84mm;
    --label-height: 124mm;
    --inner-margin: 5mm;
    --bleeds: 2mm;
    --text-size: 8pt;
    --header-01-size: 24pt;
    --nett-weight-size: 14pt;
    --weight-size: 34pt;
    --label_bg_color: #fff;
}


    @media print{
    html,body{
        width: var(--label-width);
        min-height: var(--label-height);
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        margin: 0mm !important;
        padding: 0mm !important;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    @page {
      size: var(--label-width) var(--label-height) portrait;
      min-width:var(--label-width) !important;
      min-height: var(--label-height) !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0mm !important;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    @page:left{
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    @page:right{
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    @page:bottom{
        margin-top: 0 !important;
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
    @page:first {
        size: var(--label-width) var(--label-height);
        margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
        padding: 0mm;
      }
      .print:last-child{
        page-break-after:auto;
      }
    .noPrint{
      display: none !important;
    }
  }


body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#label{
    width: var(--label-width);
    min-width: var(--label-width);
    height: var(--label-height);
    min-height: var(--label-height) !important;
    background-color: var(--label_bg_color);
    background-color: turquoise;
    padding: var(--inner-margin);
  }

#testArea{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: red !important;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="labelContainer">
    <div id="label">
        <div id="testArea"></div>
    </div>
```

Does anyone have idea how to remove that additional white "footer" ?

Comment: I descover same thing about 1:00 AM :)
Removing padding solve my problem. 
Same thing happen if I add margin to inner area.
Was trying to make it like for print. Nett dimension, dimension with bleed and a "safe margin" inside. It will be harder than it's apear :/